# error 404.0 - Not Found asp.net 5 (update1) mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I build a project with asp.net 5 Mvc6.
I run it in local host it is working correctly. Like this

http://sendfile.cc/uploads/file/201609/0.234155001475090426.png

But when I publish it and upload in my host it gives me error 404. This is my URL
http://mahdimadhani-001-site1.atempurl.com/dashboard/home

And this is my routes

```
         app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "dashboard",
                template: "dashboard/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=UnderConstructio/{id?}");              
        });
```

Please help me.

Comment: What diagnostics have you included (eg. logging) in the application? Can you reach any other pages? What is the implementation of `DashboardController.Home` (the URL includes an action name so it will not default to `Index`)?

Comment: Everybody now should go to ASP.NET Core, http://dot.net . No more ASP.NET 5 or MVC 6 please.

Comment: why when i run it on locall it is good work 
but in host it give me error 404.
i thing maybe change in web.config

Comment: .net 5 or .net core? You need to upgrade your current code to .net core 1.0.1.

Comment: i use .net 5 .thanks